# Delete administrative shares in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

how can I change the following command line, such that it deletes all shares **and not just the administrative shares listed on the command line (C$ IPC$ ADMIN$)**?

`for %i in (C$ IPC$ ADMIN$) do net share %i /delete`

Source: https://www.windows-commandline.com/disable-administrative-shares/

`for %i in (*$) do net share %i /delete`

Comment: Have you tried using a `for /f` loop to retrieve the sharenames to forward onto the deletion command? Perhaps ```@For /F "Skip=1 EOL=- Delims=$" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share 2^>NUL') Do @SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share "%%G$" /Delete```, or possibly ```@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RC:"^[^ ][^ ]*$\>"') Do @SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share %%G /Delete```.

Comment: To test either of those in a Command Prompt session, _(as opposed to the batch file commands above)_, try ```For /F "Skip=1 EOL=- Delims=$" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share 2^>NUL') Do @Echo=SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share "%G$" /Delete```, or ```For /F %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RC:"^[^ ][^ ]*$\>"') Do @Echo=SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share %G /Delete``` as needed. If it displays what you wanted, remove the `Echo=`, and run it again to perform the deletion.

Comment: @Compo


**Hi Compo, 

first of all thank you very much for the feedback. In your command line ONLY consider the administrative shares, I intend to delete all shares, not just the administrative shares.

Many thanks in advance,

michele-tn**

Comment: How about trying a few modifications yourself, to not rely on the `$` character, instead of expecting sombody to just do it all for you! My comment was to offer you the idea to use a `for /f` loop, the rest should be down to you. Perhaps ```For /F "Skip=1 EOL=-" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share 2^>NUL') Do @Echo=SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe Share "%G" /Delete``` will get you closer. _(This version should get all shares not beginning with `-` and without whitespace.)_

Comment: **Thanks a lot for the feedback.

BATCH programming is not my comfort zone.


Thank you..**